# Read mp3 tags in android application

Tags: java, android, tags, mp3

I use jid3lib for java. When i'm working with this library on file that stored in my computer it works great, but when I try to read mp3 tags of files on the emulator's sdcard I got Exeption.

I use the following code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    File musicPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);

    File[] songs = musicPath.listFiles();

    for (int i=0; i < songs.length; i++){
        try {
            MP3File song = new MP3File(new File(songs[i].getPath()));
            Log.d("TEST", song.getID3v1Tag().getAlbum() );

        } catch (TagException e) {
            Log.d("TEST", "Tag Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("TEST", "Exception");             
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I put 2 mp3 files in the sdcard, but I still got Exception in the Log.
What can be the problem here?

I got the following error at the LogCat:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/Music/song.mp3: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

But when I'm looking in the File Explorer of the DDMS I can see the files under this path, and even if I use a loop in order to print the file's names It show the correct names.

Comment: Can you post the Exception message or StackTrace ?

Comment: Question was edited @Pratik

Comment: try to use MediaColumn ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns.html )

Answer (score 1):

> EACCES (Permission denied)

Add [`READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission in manifest file.

And, maybe `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` also.

Comment: I add it but it still happens.
I also add WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and the problem was fixed.
Why I have to add this permission in order to read tags?

Comment: @GalVanunu Probably the library opens that file in R/W mode.