# How can I extract Info from an selected mp3 file?

Tags: android, audio, kotlin, mediastore

I want to get some info like artist, duration and title from a selected mp3 file.But I seem to get something wrong. I just get some random numbers and that is not what I hoped for. I am thankful for every help I get.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_music)
    SelectTrack()
}




private fun SelectTrack() {

   val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
   intent.type = "audio/mpeg"
   startActivityForResult(intent, 0)

}

var selectedTrackUri: Uri? = null


  override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

      if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data !=null) {

          selectedTrackUri = data.data



         val title =  MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE.toString()
         val duration = MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION.toString()
         val artist = MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST.toString()

         AddTrackName_txt.text = title
         AddArtistName_txt.text = artist
         AddTrackLength_txt.text = duration
         //Picasso.get().load(album).into(AddTrackPic_View)

      }
  }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read mp3 tags in android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200852/read-mp3-tags-in-android-application)

Comment: @shkschneider Actually, is not a duplicated of that question

Comment: Indeed, the issue was different. I was just recalling it from the `MP3File` usage in it. I revert my closing flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the way you retrieve the metadata of the file, you are assigning the values of the `keys` used to extract the metadata, not reading the actual data from the `MediaMetadataRetriever`.

**Example**

```
private fun selectTrack() {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).apply { type = "audio/mpeg" }
    startActivityForResult(intent, RC_MEDIA_FILE)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent)

    if (requestCode == RC_MEDIA_FILE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && intent != null) {
        val mmr = MediaMetadataRetriever()
        mmr.setDataSource(this, intent.data)

        val title = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE)
        val artist = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST)
        val duration = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION)

        Log.d("MP3", "title=$title, artist=$artist, duration=$duration")
    }
}

companion object {
    const val RC_MEDIA_FILE = 100
}
```

**Output**

`D/MP3: title=Sweet Child O´Mine, artist=Guns N' Roses, duration=356444`

Comment: Thank you so much, you really helped me! I wish you a merry xmas and a happy new year!

Comment: for me it doesn't work for audio files for some reason, only video files, e.g. when trying to get `MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION`